# Patch 1.2 disabled cheetah speed, but I can still select it in game. Is this a bug?

Tags: simcity-2013

I read in the news that there's no cheetah speed, but the option is in my game, so which is it?

Comment: @Tater596 yeah, that's good.

Comment: You can re-enable cheetah-speed with the SimCity SpeedBooster http://redd.it/1a1j37

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update: 2013-04-05, Cheetah speed is switched back on.  It is now 2x llama speed.

---

Cheetah was once slowed to llama speed.  You could still activate it, but it wouldn't go faster than medium speed.

[Patch Notes](https://help.ea.com/article/simcity-patch-notes)

> Patch 1.2
>
> Cheetah speed has been disabled, selecting it will not cause your SimCity to run any faster than at Llama speed.

Comment: Press comment about whole situation http://www.polygon.com/2013/3/7/4075120/simcity-servers-update-maxis-disabling-features

Comment: We should keep an eye on this, as this may be something that a future patch resets to the original intent.